# Data Inputs not updating in MS ACCES

Tags: vb.net

When I Save new record on my database, (I am using gridview) it works fine but when I close it and open it again the data that I have entered is gone How can I fix this? (I have already entered datas in my database (I am using MS ACCES) before I connected it to my project for sql sysntax reasons, I also cant edit/delete the datas).

MY CODE:

```
Public Class RegisterClient
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\bin\Release\VetSystemDatabase.accdb") 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Serafin\Documents\VetSystemDatabase.accdb
    Dim sql As String
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    Sub loadrecord()
        Try
            Dim sql As String
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            con.Open()
            sql = "Select * from Register"
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            da.SelectCommand = cmd

            da.Fill(dt)

            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close()

        End Try


    End Sub
    Private Sub btnloadrecord_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnloadrecord.Click
        loadrecord()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click

        Try
            con.Open()
            sql = "INSERT INTO Register (LastName,Firstname,Adress,CellphoneNo,TelephoneNo,Email,PetName,Specie,Breed,Weight,Color,Gender,Age,DiagnosisType,DateOfDiagnosis) VALUES ('" & LName.Text & "', '" & FName.Text & "', '" & Address.Text & "', " & Val(CellNo.Text) & ", " & Val(TelNo.Text) & ", '" & Email.Text & "', '" & PetName.Text & "', '" & Specie.Text & "', '" & Breed.Text & "', " & Val(Weight.Text) & " , '" & Color.Text & "', '" & Gender.Text & "', " & Val(Age.Text) & ", '" & Diagnosis.Text & "', " & Val(Dates.Text) & ");"
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = sql

            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            If i > 0 Then
                MsgBox("New record has been inserted successfully!")


            Else
                MsgBox("No record has been inserted successfully!")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close()
            loadrecord()
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        Me.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        LName.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        FName.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        Address.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
        CellNo.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString()
        TelNo.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
        Email.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString()
        PetName.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString()
        Specie.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value.ToString()
        Breed.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value.ToString()
        Weight.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(10).Value.ToString()
        Color.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(11).Value.ToString()
        Gender.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(12).Value.ToString()
        Age.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(13).Value.ToString()
        Diagnosis.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(14).Value.ToString()
        Dates.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(15).Value.ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnupdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnupdate.Click


        Try
            con.Open()
            sql = "UPDATE Register SET LastName='" & LName.Text & "',Firstname='" & FName.Text & "',Adress='" & Address.Text & "',CellphoneNo=" & Val(CellNo.Text) & ",TelephoneNo=" & Val(TelNo.Text) & ",Email='" & Email.Text & "',PetName='" & PetName.Text & "',Specie='" & Specie.Text & "',Breed='" & Breed.Text & "',Weight=" & Val(Weight.Text) & ",Color='" & Color.Text & "',Gender='" & Gender.Text & "',Age=" & Val(Age.Text) & ",DiagnosisType='" & Diagnosis.Text & "',DateOfDiagnosis=" & Val(Dates.Text) & " WHERE ID=" & Val(Me.Text) & ";"
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = sql

            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            If i > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Record has been UPDATED successfully!")

            Else
                MsgBox("No record has been UPDATED!")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close()
            loadrecord()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



        Try
            con.Open()
            sql = "Delete * from Register WHERE ID=" & Val(Me.Text) & ""
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = sql

            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            If i > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Record has been deleted successfully!")

            Else
                MsgBox("No record has been deleted!")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close()
            loadrecord()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Dashboard.Show()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Male_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Male.CheckedChanged
        If Male.Checked Then
            Gender.Text = Male.Text
        End If
        If Female.Checked Then
            Gender.Text = Female.Text
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I hope you guys under stand what I said but for simplicity of what I said:
 1. I run my project
 2. I enter new data
 3. The data I have entered was saved on my datagrid
 4. I close the project
 5. I run again the project
 6. The data I have entered is gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's amazing how many times people mess up using a local data file and it's because they don't read enough or follow the instructions they do read.  Here's how it should work:

You start by creating an Access database wherever is convenient, e.g. your *Documents* folder. You then, using either the *Project* menu or by right-clicking the project in the *Solution Explorer*, add an existing item to your project and select that data file. When prompted, you say "yes" to having the data file copied into your project. You can now delete the original file if you like and the file in your project folder is your source of truth. Any time you want to change the database schema or add some default data, you do it to the file in the project folder, opening it from the *Solution Explorer*.

By default, every time you build your project, that source file will be copied to the output folder, along with your EXE. By default, your project gets built every time you run it. If there are no code changes then no build takes place, so neither the EXE or the data file are updated. If there are code changes since the last time you ran your project, the project is built and both the EXE and the data file are updated, with the source data file being copied over any existing data file in the output folder.

When your project is running, it's the copy in the output folder that your app connects to. Any changes you make to data are made in that copy. If you then make code changes and run your project again, the source file is copied over the file in the output folder and your changes are lost. This is the #1 reason that beginners think that there data changes are not being saved. The data is being saved but they are just not looking in the right place or at the right time for them. The changes are not made to the source file and they will be gone from the output copy after a build.

The solution to this "issue" is to change the properties for the data file. Select it in the Solution Explorer and then change `Copy to output directory` from `Copy always` to `Copy if newer`. After that, the source data file will only be copied to the output folder on a build if you have made changes to the source file. Of course you will want to make a new copy if that source file has a changed schema or contains different default data. Otherwise, your output copy will remain untouched, meaning that the changes you make to the data in the copy while testing will be retained between runs, even if you make code changes.

With that in mind, your connection string is almost certainly wrong. If you have added your source file to the project at the top level then it will be copied to the same folder as the EXE on a build. That means that this:

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\bin\Release\VetSystemDatabase.accdb")
```

should be this:

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\VetSystemDatabase.accdb")
```

In Windows apps that are not ClickOnce deployed, the "|DataDirectory|" placeholder resolves to the folder that the EXE was run from. It doesn't matter whether you're running the project in the debugger, testing a Release build or running the app on a different machine after deployment, that connection string will just work because it will always find the data file in the same folder as the EXE.

If you add the source file to a folder in the project then that same folder structure will be created in the output folder, but there's no way that the folder structure you're using is appropriate. Let's say that you don't want your data file in the same folder as the EXE but, rather, in a *data* subfolder. In that case, you start by adding a *data* subfolder to your project and then add the source data file to it. That same structure will then be created in the output folder and your connection strung becomes this:

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\data\VetSystemDatabase.accdb")
```

Again, it will just work, no matter where you run your app.

That said, it's generally better to store your connection string in the application config file and read it from there at run time. That way, it's possible to move the data file somewhere else and then update the config file to reflect that.

Comment: Though I have not fully understand how this works because english is not my first language but after changing the setting in solution explorer to COPY ALWAYS to COPY IF NEWER solved my problem. you are such a big help. THANK YOU KIND SIR!.